# PHP system() executes twice, while exec() don't

Tags: debian, php

I have problem:
when I execute command using system() it runs 2 times, but not when I use exec()

**test.php**

```
echo "something" . PHP;
```

|

**testSystem.php**

```
system(__DIR__ . "/test.php"); // runs 2 times
```

**testExec.php**

```
exec(__DIR__ . "/test.php"); // runs 1 time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, your "system" call is not executed twice really.  According to PHP manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

*system — Execute an external program **and** display the output.*

please, compare to
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Php's "system" command runs the "testSystem.php" script, catches the output, which is "something", than the system command is providing you the scripts output (run only once) which is "something".

So in fact, "system" command just repeats the script output, without running it twice.

To be sure, you can change the testSystem.php to write (append) "something" into a text file. You will probably see only one, single entry for each script call.